# Safari search bar won't autofill anymore

Tags: safari

It's been a couple of weeks now since autofill on Safari's search bar suddenly stopped working.

If I quit (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>) and reopen Safari, everything works fine, but after a few minutes, the search bar doesn't autocomplete what I am typing.

Actually, the whole search bar gets blocked, and I can't even see the preview of any open tab in Safari (see picture below):

[image]

The only thing that solves the issue is to quit Safari, which is  quite annoying. Any hints?

Comment: Are you running ay extensions?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this behavior is so abnormal that it is likely a corruption or problem with your system, as opposed to an error in the setup or configuration of Safari that could be fixed. So you will just have to do troubleshooting until something works. Some possibilities:

0. Disable all extensions.
1. Turn off and on the Smart Search settings:
   [image: Safari Search Preferences]
2. Delete the Safari Autofill corrections database at ~/Library/Safari/AutoFillCorrections.db
3. And/or all of the files in that directory could be the issue.
4. Observe that directory after you start Safari- do any of the files get modified at the same time the problem in Safari occurs? Also check the Preferences files at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari*
5. Delete the Safari cache files at ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/

So, no magic bullets here, just some things to try. Good luck.

Comment: Deleting AutoFillCorrections.db (and I also deleted AutoFillCorrections.db-shm and AutoFillCorrections.db-wal) instantly solves the problem for me, but it doesn't last very long and I have to do it again. Unlike the OP, my issue is not solved by restarting Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe turn off "Show search engine suggestions" in the Search tab in Preferences? Or any of the options for "Smart Search Field"?

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it doesn't work.